# Connect to network - network is unreachable

Tags: networking, wireless, server, network-manager, dns

Although I am able to browse the net just fine I keep getting network unreachable when I run a download using my Java program. It was working fine till yesterday but now it is suddenly giving me problems. Ping retrieves the packets just fine. I have wireless internet.

Here is my `/etc/network/interface`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo


iface lo inet loopback
```

This is the output of `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether f8:bc:12:58:40:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::fabc:12ff:fe58:40e4/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and my `/etc/resolv.conf` is

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

My ip route show outputs as

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto static 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.100 metric 1
```